# Thread scheduler registration?

Tags: java, multithreading

In java, does `run()` register a thread in a thread scheduler?

What about `construct()`,`start()` and `register()` ?

Comment: What do you mean by construct() and register()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In java, does run() register a thread in a thread scheduler?

No.  If you call the `run()` method directly, it is called as a normal method; i.e. it runs on the current thread, not a new one.

> What about construct(),start() and register()

The `start` method creates a new thread, and in the process the thread will be registered with the scheduler.  (However, the scheduler is a nebulous concept in Java.  It is implied that one must exist, but its implementation and behavior are typically left to the host operating system.  A pure Java program has almost no control over the way that the thread scheduler actually works.)

There are no `construct()` or `register()` methods in the `Thread` API.  If you are referring to the `Thread` constructors, they only create a `Thread` object, and NOT the underlying thread that will do the work.  The latter is only created when `start()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

`run()` is the actual code in the thread; so you could do like:

```
Thread childThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // do stuff on a new thread
    }
};
```

(Though I've been told extending Thread like that is ugly ;)

So calling run() itself won't create a new thread. To do that, you use start():

```
childThread.start();
```

So, I guess it does give the scheduler a new thread to deal with -- but that's way down on the OS level.

I'm not sure what you mean by `construct()` and `register()` though?